# How to convert world space rotation into viewport space rotation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I covert the rotation (pose) of an object in the world coordinate frame into the rotation (pose) in the viewport space?

I know the `Camera` object provides a `WorldToViewpointPoint` method for transforming points/`Vector3d`, but how can I transform a rotation (`Quaternion`) or how can I obtain the transformation matrix from world to viewport coordinates?  Do I also need to consider scale?

Ideally I'd like a quaternion or Euler angles representing the target object's pose in viewport space (i.e. relative to the camera).

Note: the `Camera.worldToCameraMatrix` does not provide the same transformation as the `Camera.WorldToViewpoint()` method, implying that camera coordinates are not the same as viewport coordinates.

Comment: @SerkanPekçetin - I don't think that is the same, since I'm wanting viewport coordinates, not camera coordinates.  The documentation doesn't seem consistent with terminology regarding world vs viewport vs view vs camera vs screen, so it isn't clear to me.

Comment: I see your point, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Do you mean, the rotation needed to go from "aligned with the camera in all local axis" (the camera space equivalent to "no rotation") to some known world rotation?